# C# Add Ranks to listelements in a certain way

Tags: c#, list, ranking

I got a list with teams sorted by their score

```
Team G, Score:7
Team A, Score:5
Team X, Score:4
Team Y, Score:4
Team T, Score:3
Team K, Score:3
Team P, Score:2
Team L, Score:2
Team E, Score:1
Team R, Score:1
Team O, Score:1
Team Q, Score:1
```

Now I am ranking these Teams by their score.

```
public static void AddRankByScore(List<TeamExtended> teams)
    {
        if (teams == null) return;
        var rank = 1;

        foreach (var team in teams)
        {
            team.Rank= $"{rank}";
            rank++;
        }
    }
```

The result looks like this

```
Team G, Score:7, Rank:1
Team A, Score:5, Rank:2
Team X, Score:4, Rank:3
Team Y, Score:4, Rank:4
Team T, Score:3, Rank:5
Team K, Score:3, Rank:6
Team P, Score:2, Rank:7
Team L, Score:2, Rank:8
Team E, Score:1, Rank:9
Team R, Score:1, Rank:10
Team O, Score:1, Rank:11
Team Q, Score:1, Rank:12
```

But I want the ranks to look like this

```
Team G, Score:7, Rank:1
Team A, Score:5, Rank:2
Team X, Score:4, Rank:3
Team Y, Score:4, Rank:3
Team T, Score:3, Rank:5
Team K, Score:3, Rank:5
Team P, Score:2, Rank:7
Team L, Score:2, Rank:7
Team E, Score:1, Rank:9
Team R, Score:1, Rank:9
Team O, Score:1, Rank:9
Team Q, Score:1, Rank:9
```

How do I do that? I have to skip some ranks if teams have the same score.

Comment: Sort `teams` by `Score` and then skip rank increment for the same score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a check that sees if the score is equal to the `lastscore` we checked. If it is we start counting up our `equalplacing` variable to increase the score, after `lastscore` changed, according to the amount of teams on the same spot.

```cs
// Last score that team had.
int lastscore = 0;
// Amount of placings on the same spot.
int equalplacing = 1;
// Current rank.
int rank = 0;

foreach (var team in teams) {
    // Check if current team score is not equal to the last team score.
    if (team.Score != lastscore) {
       rank += equalplacing;
       equalplacing = 1;
    }
    else {
        equalplacing++;
    }
    
    team.Rank = rank;
    lastscore = team.Score;
}
```

To make sure the ranking works you need to sort the list in desceding order with the score as the sort value. You can do that with Linq and `.OrderByDescending()`.

```cs
teams = teams.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Score).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Group and order the `Team` objects by the `Score` property, increment the rank counter by each group's count instead of `1` to get the desired output.

`LINQ` example:

```cs
public static void AddRankByScore(List<TeamExtended> teams) => teams
    .GroupBy(x => x.Score)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
    .Aggregate(1, (r, g) =>
    {
        g.Aggregate(0, (_, t) => t.Rank = r);
        r += g.Count();
        return r;
    });
```

`foreach` example:

```cs
public static void AddRankByScore(List<TeamExtended> teams)
{
    var r = 1;

    foreach (var g in teams
        .GroupBy(x => x.Score)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key))
    {
        foreach (var t in g)
            t.Rank = r;

        r += g.Count();
    }
}
```

Each of which modifies the `Rank` properties of the given list (`teams`) as follows:

```
G, 7, 1
A, 5, 2
X, 4, 3
Y, 4, 3
T, 3, 5
K, 3, 5
P, 2, 7
L, 2, 7
E, 1, 9
R, 1, 9
O, 1, 9
Q, 1, 9
```